# Pass variables to mutation component - react-apollo

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I have these mutation methods and I want to refractor it so the mutation component takes in the variables props. In this instance they are available when mounting that component as params.

So currently these are the methods that I have:

```
  handleInterestClick = (registerInterest: MutationFn) =>
  async () => {
    const { match: { params: { idea } } } = this.props;
    const result = await registerInterest({
      variables: {
        ideaId: idea,
      },
    });

    const { data: { registerInterest: { error } } } = result;
    if (error) {
      throw {
        type: 'RegisterInterest',
        error,
      };
    }
    return this.closeModal();
  }

  renderAdditionInterestCTA = () => {
    return (
      <Mutation mutation={REGISTER_INTEREST}>
        {(registerInterest: MutationFn) => {
          const handleClick = this.handleAdditionInterestClick(registerInterest);
          return (
            <ModalButton onClick={handleClick} context="primary">{i18n.t('client.apps.interest.cta')}</ModalButton>
          );
        }}
      </Mutation>
    );
  };
```

If I were to pass the variables to the mutation component would it be like this `<Mutation mutation={REGISTER_INTEREST} variables={{ ideaId: idea}}>`? and how do I refractor the `handleInterestClick`?